# Is there a way to catch exceptions without breaking loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, exception

In Java, there's a difference between a loop surrounded with a try-catch block if an exception could be thrown inside the while loop, and a statement surrounded by a try-catch block inside a loop.

For instance, the following code snippets are different:

---

**Snippet 1:**

```
try {
    for (File file : files) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        System.out.println("OK!");
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException exc) {
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

*^This code snippet breaks the loop if a* `FileNotFoundException` *is thrown. So if a file cannot be read, then the loop breaks and Java will stop reading further files.*

---

**Snippet 2:**

```
for (File file : files) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        System.out.println("OK!");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
}
```

*^This code snippet does not break the loop if an exception is thrown, if an exception occurs, the code catches the exception and continues to the next element in* `files`*. With other words, it won't stop reading the files.*

---

Now I want to read a certain file in a directory (say **bananas.xml**), and, unregarded if that file is readable or not—the XML file is a metadata file, which might not be required for the program to run—, read the corresponding directory (which is **bananas**):

```
File main = new File("/home/MCEmperor/test");
File fruitMeta = new File(main, "bananas.xml");
FileInputStream fruitInputStream = new FileInputStream(fruitMeta); // This code COULD throw a FileNotFoundException
// Do something with the fruitInputStream...

File fruitDir = new File(main, "bananas");
if (fruitDir.exists() && fruitDir.canRead()) {
    File[] listBananas = fruitDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : listBananas) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); // This code COULD throws a FileNotFoundException
        // Do something with the fis...
    }
}
```

Now two lines in the snippet above may throw a `FileNotFoundException` and I don't want to break the loop.

Now is there a way to make one try-catch block with catches both lines if an exception is thrown, but without breaking the `for`-loop?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Why not just use two different try-catch blocks?

Comment: Just a pet peeve of mine for exceptions in general, but you are using an exception for something that you are expecting. That doesn't sound like an exception to me, but a good case for an `if(!exists){continue}`.

Comment: There are several reasons why a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown; in Windows, this exception is also thrown when the file is not accessible, for some strange reason.

Comment: What loop?  If you mean the `for (File...` loop, why would you even enter that if fruitDir wasn't found?

Comment: @HotLicks fruitMeta is the one that wasn't found.

Comment: Then catch the exception there and continue, if that's what you want.  But you say you won't continue if that file doesn't exist, so you're asking for two conflicting things.

Comment: @HotLicks: There's only one loop in the snippet: the for-loop. Plus, if **bananas.xml** wasn't found, still read the **bananas** directory, since the xml file only contains metadata, which may not be required for the programme to run.

Comment: Up until 23 minutes ago (just before you posted the above comment) you said "and if that file is readable, then I want to read the corresponding directory (which is bananas)".  Glad you're finally getting your act together.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yeah, trick. That was an error in the original post. My bad. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
FileInputStream fruitInputStream = getFileInputStream(fruitMeta);
...
fis = getFileInputStream(file);

private static FileInputStream getFileInputStream(File file) {
    try {
        return new FileInputStream(file);
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited away an unsafe alternative solution.